# Format of the address is invalid in IdeaMart Subscription API

Tags: ideamart

I want to subscribe to users to my Ideamart mobile app. This is the sample request I sent to the ideamart API

```
{
  "applicationId": "APP_01234",
  "password": "xxxxx",
  "action": "1",
  "subscriberId": "tel:94761234567"
}
```

This is the response I got

```
{
  "statusDetail": "Format of the address is invalid.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "statusCode": "E1325"
}
```

How should I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurred because the user was not subscribed the application. User must subscribe it first to use the CAAS api.

Comment: අඩෝ ඕක ඉතිං කියන්න දෙයක්යැ බං. අප් වෝට් එකක් ඕනැමද?

Answer (score 1):

try after recharging(reload) your mobile account